# Issue saving PDF with MIMEKIT

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, mimekit

I have a MIME file (not an e-mail) that has a multipart body to it. One of the parts is xml while the other is Application\PDF. When trying to save the PDF, it will not open. I am probably just not doing it correctly (as a file saves, but Adobe says that the file is corrupt when trying to open it).

I am using the following code: (NOTE: In this snippet, I am simply retrieving the information from the file and then saving it to a database. I later extract the data from the database and create the file. I know it is not the saving to/from the DB that is the problem as that has been thoroughly tested. It is in this method that is causing my problem.)

```
foreach (var part in _mimeMessage.BodyParts)
{
    if (part is MimePart)
    {
        var p = part as MimePart;

        if (p.ContentId == name)
        {
            using (var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
            {
                p.ContentObject.WriteTo(stream);

                return stream.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there something I am missing in doing this?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the issue is that the files that I had were "double encoded" using base64. I got help from someone on the MimeKit forums, and here is the code that ended up working for me.

```
            foreach (var attachment in _mimeMessage.BodyParts.OfType<MimePart>())
        {
            if (attachment.ContentId != name)
                continue;

            using (var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())//File.Create(@"C:\Client Test Data\Alert Files\" + name))
            {
                using (var filtered = new FilteredStream(stream))
                {
                    filtered.Add(DecoderFilter.Create("base64"));
                    attachment.ContentObject.DecodeTo(filtered);

                    return stream.ToArray();
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are saving the encoded content. You need to save the *decoded* content. Like this:

```
p.ContentObject.DecodeTo(stream);
```